# WSO2 IS 5.3.0 Unable to change attribute list in user profile

Tags: user-profile, wso2-identity-server

I have setup WSO2 IS 5.3.0 with an Active Directory as secundary user store.
I am able to find users from the AD, and view their user profile in the management console.
I would now like to modify the list of attributes that are displayed in the user profile screen. I already found documentation saying I should edit the corresponding claims, setting the attribute 'Supported by Default' to true for the desired claims, and also setting the desired number in the 'Display Order' attribute. So I modified some local claims, but these changes have no effect on the User Profile screen: I keep getting the same original list of attributes (First Name, Last Name, Organisation, Country, ...). Can anyone tell me what I could be doing wrong ?

The secondary user store is configured with the following settings:
[screenshot AD configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91efV.png)

This is the [user profile screen for my user account in the AD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AzEZ.png).

An example of a claim modification is for the local Country claim  where I set the 'Supported by Default' to false and changing the 'Display Order' from 4 to 0. When opening the user profile screen again, the content remains unchanged (country field is still there).

Another example is when I try to add another claim in the user profile screen, such as the local Date of Birth claim, by setting the 'Supported by Default' to true and changing the 'Display Order' from 0 to 4. Again, nothing changes in the user profile screen either (date of birth field is not present).

For the Organisation claim that is present in the user profile screen, but that is currently empty, I added an attribute mapping to the 'company' attribute that exists in the AD, but when looking at the user profile screen again, this field remains empty.

Let me know if any further details are needed (I would have added some more screenshots, but as a new user on this forum, I'm currently limited to 2 links in my posts...).

Comment: Please share your code with us, tell us what you have done already, how to reproduce the problem etc. Show your work...

Comment: What is the Identity Server version you are using?

Comment: @Maduranga: It's version 5.3.0

Comment: Update: We have installed a second instance of WSO2 IS, and there, it works fine. The only difference in config, is that the first instance has been setup with an oracle DB, while the 2nd instance used the internal H2 DB. I have not found any error messages in the oracle DB logs that indicate any issues with it. We can also see that modified claim data are correctly written in the corresponding claim tables. So I don't see why WSO2 IS doesn't take these changes into account when displaying the user profile screen. Has anyone else had similar issues when using an Oracle DB with WSO2 IS?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I did a complete reinstallation (including setting up an oracle DB as carbon DB instead of the H2 DB), and this time everything works correctly. Something must have gone wrong during the first installation.